# Can Amazon API Gateway specify TTL for each path?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-api-gateway

Hi！ I’m a beginner of AWS. I’m curious about whether Amazon API Gateway can cache by path? And control every path’s TTL?

For example:

```
Path1 cache TTL=60,
Path2 no-cache TTL=0,
Path3 cache TTL=3600
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Here is the official documentation: [Enabling API caching to enhance responsiveness - Override API Gateway stage-level caching for method caching](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-caching.html#override-api-gateway-stage-cache-for-method-cache)

Here is describes precisely what you are requesting.

> You can override stage-level cache settings by enabling or disabling caching for a specific method. By increasing or decreasing its TTL period; or by turning encryption on or off for cached responses.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. it seems like possible to set TTL by each "resource method". I will have a try!